# Select text files depending on their names in recursive folders, zip them

Tags: bash, zip

I have a directory structure like this

- B01
- B02
- B12
- B17R
- B35
  ...

In each directory i have a lot of archive files.
I would like select all files containing in their filename "2019", zip them (and finally delete them) to get these files

- B01_2019.zip
- B02_2019.zip
- B12_2019.zip
- B17R_2019.zip
- B35_2019.zip

What is the most efficient way to achieve it in bash ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Awk is an option here:

```
find /parentdir -maxdepth 2 -name "*2019*" | awk -F\/ '{ print "zip /"$2"/"$3"/"$3"_2019.zip "$0" && rm "$0 }'
```

We get the output from the find command then print the commands required for each entry based on the forward slash delimited fields as specified by -F/

Once we have verified that the command read as required (this step is very important!) we can use awk's system function to execute the commands and so:

```
find /parentdir -maxdepth 2 -name "*2019*" | awk -F\/ '{ system("zip /"$2"/"$3"/"$3"_2019.zip "$0" && rm "$0) }'
```

Comment: Globally, the proposed "function" works. However, there is only one zip file at the end (not a big deal for me). Moreover, it seems that the code is very slow (about 5 hours for 13 000 files of 90 Ko), is it normal?

Comment: Looping through the results and parsing the output natively through bash without awk would be more efficient but would require more coding. When you say only one zip file at the end, are you saying only one zip file is being created?

Comment: Indeed, if a zip all the files directly, it takes only 5 minutes... And, only one zip file is created with all the architecture of the initial directory. It is not a big deal...
I find an alternative
First creating a list of the files:
find /home/user/BUfile/ -name '\*_2019\*' > list.txt
THen zip the list
cat list.txt | zip -@ BU_2019.zip
I thin i could try to perform the search and the zipping recursively but i need to search again